# How to override package.json "latest" dist-tag with version from package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

I want to use `latest` distribution tag in my `package.json` for internal packages. This allows me to always get their latest versions when I `npm install` in local environment, without updating all external 3rd parties.

The issue comes when I'm hotfixing deployed verion:

- For hotfix purpose I generate and save `package-lock.json` for each deployed version of the application.
- But when I `npm install` during hotfix preparation, there is a conflict between versions of internal package in `package.json` and `package-lock.json`: `package-lock.json` points to version that was used in deployed application, but `package.json` point to `latest` distribution tag, which itself points to later version.
- Since version specified in `package-lock.json` doesn't suit to version range specified in `package.json` (which is very specific - only the latest version will suit), `npm install` ignores `package-lock.json` and installs the latest version.

I searched through documentation and internet and didn't find any existing solution for the issue:

- I didn't find any `npm install` flag that would treat `package-lock.json` versions with higher priority than distribution tag in `package.json`
- I dind't find any tool that would reconstruct `package.json` from `package-lock.json`, or at least replace aliases (distribution tags) in `package.json` with specific versions from `package-lock.json`.

Is there any solution for my issue (besides writing a tool that will implement last approach)?

*Sandbox:*
https://github.com/maxlk/npm-lock-version-should-override-latest (clone and run `npm install` or its alternative)

Comment: Use `npm update`, it will take it from package-lock.json.

Comment: @kiranmalvi doesn't work for me, example: https://github.com/maxlk/npm-lock-version-should-override-latest Just clone and run `npm update` - latest version of lodash is installed instead of 4.0.0. My npm version is 6.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution - to use `npm ci` instead of `npm install`.

It doesn't exit with error, despite the claim in the documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci

> If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in `package.json`, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.